# how to Sort mysql results by like query?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to sort mysql results by like clause.

```
$query="select * from table where id!='a'";
if(!empty($getSearch)){
    $search_exploded = explode ( " ", $getSearch );
    $x = 0;
    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
        $x++;
        if( $x == 1 ){
            $query .="and title LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        } else{ 
            $query .=" or title LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        }
        $sorting=" order by CASE WHEN title LIKE '%$search_each%' THEN 1 WHEN title LIKE '%$search_each%' THEN 2 else 3 end";
    }
```

This code is working but it shows the results of everything matched with $search_each...
I want to get the best results matched with the whole search i.e. $getSearch... but I also want to show related results if users misspell a word that's the reason I exploded $getSearch into $search_each... I'm confused can anybody help???

Comment: Consider switching to a FULLTEXT index

Comment: I don't have much knowledge... can you elaborate...